# SQL state: 42883 in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the following table called as `test_type` which contains two columns namely `cola` and `colb`.

**Table**: `test_type`

```
create table test_type
(
    cola int,
    colb varchar(50)
);
```

Now I want to create a type with same columns.

**Type**: `type1`

```
create type type1 as
(
cola int,
colb varchar(50)
);
```

Here I have created function in which I am passing type name `type1` to insert the data to the 
table `test_type`.

--Creating Function

```
create or replace function fun_test ( p_Type type1 )
returns void
as
$$
begin
    insert into test_type(cola,colb) 
    select cola,colb from p_type
    EXCEPT
    select cola,colb from test_type;
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

---Calling Function

```
SELECT fun_test(1,'Xyz');
```

**Error Details**:

```
ERROR: function fun_test(integer, unknown) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 8
```

Comment: `select cola,colb from p_type` will not work. You don't have a table with that name - at least not in the example you have shown. If your intention is to pass a table name as a parameter, then this will not work. You need dynamic SQL for that. See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22753868/330315 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10705616/330315 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33701082/330315

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Yeah! I got it. Thank you so much for providing useful links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "pack" the arguments together: `(1,'xs')`, so that postgres recognise them as single argument of type type1:

```
SELECT fun_test((1,'xs'));
```

For a better readability you can cast the argument to type1 (not really necessary):

```
SELECT fun_test((1,'xs')::type1);
```

If the purpose of the function is to to insert the values only if they are not already contained in the table, you could change your code so:

```
create or replace function fun_test ( p_Type type1 )
  returns void AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test_type(cola,colb)
    SELECT p_Type.cola,p_Type.colb
    EXCEPT
    SELECT cola,colb FROM test_type;
END; 
$$ language plpgsql;
```

But this syntax is my opinion not good readable. This statement looks better:

```
...
BEGIN
  PERFORM 0 FROM test_type WHERE (cola, colb) = p_Type;
  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO test_type(cola,colb) VALUES (p_Type.cola,p_Type.colb);
  END IF;
END;
...
```

Comment: Still getting an error but this time different relation `p_Type` does not exists.

Comment: This only means that the table p_type does not exist. Create it and it will exist.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Check out the answer again, I added some code. I hope now I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes! This is what my question is. But I still accept it because this --> `SELECT fun_test((1,'xs'));` solve my error and I did it with different way by casting `p_Type` to `type1`. Anyway its really a good idea what you have written in last statement.